# \ifx doesn't treat \noexpand as \relax

Tags: tex-core, expansion

The TeXbook (20th printing, Addison-Wesley 1991) describes how the primitive `\noexpand<token>` is expanded (p. 213):

> The expansion is the token itself; but that token is interpreted as if its meaning were ‘`\relax`’ if it is a control sequence that would ordinarily be expanded by TeX’s expansion rules.

In light of this I expect the following plain TeX manuscript to typeset "yes". In fact, it typesets "no". Why?

```
\def\foo{bar}%
\expandafter\ifx\noexpand\foo\relax yes\else no\fi%
\bye
```

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Going by your logic, `\expandafter\meaning\noexpand\foo` is just like `\meaning\foo` and should therefore typeset "macro:->bar", but in fact it typesets "\relax".

Comment: I see, yes I probably don't understand everything here.

Comment: I suppose you *could* argue that `\foo` in this context is *not* a control sequence that would ordinarily be expanded by TeX’s expansion rules. For `\ifx` does *not* expand; it only checks whether two tokens mean the same. Unfortunately, this “explanation” does not explain the difference between `\ifx` and `\meaning`: The latter does not expand its argument either. I suppose it boils down to reading the TeX source code (which I never tried).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to look first at module 358 of `tex.web`, where *no_expand_flag* is defined to be 257 (the comment says this characterizes a special variant of *relax*). When a macro is preceded by `\noexpand`, the variable *cur_chr* is assigned *no_expand_flag* and *cur_cmd* is assigned *relax*.

[image]

Module 507 explains how `\ifx` works: first the next token is stored, along with its *cur_cmd* and *cur_chr* values in *p* and *q*; thereafter, another token is absorbed and its *cur_cmd* is compared with *p*. In your case, this test returns true, because both values are *relax*.

However, now *b* (the return value of the conditional) is returned the truth value of *cur_chr* = *q* and these don't match.

[image]

The conclusion is that the expansion of `\noexpand\foo` is `\relax`, but not as far as `\ifx` is concerned and that this is by design.

Comment: Thanks! What is `cur_chr` normally, for tokens that are not flagged as temporarily non-expandable?

Comment: By the way, I disagree with your statement that "the conclusion is that ... this is by design". By definition you cannot tell whether a certain implementation is by design by merely reading the code; the design must be clearly specified in a meta-language, e.g. in comments or in the documentation. Otherwise, every bug would be "by design".

Comment: @EvanAad “this characterizes a special variant of *relax*” seems to me clear enough a statement that this *relax* is not the same as one the user can input as `\relax`. The values assigned to *cur_chr* are clearly explained in `tex.web`.