# Statements about \noexpand in source3.pdf and in the TeXbook

Tags: tex-core, expl3, primitives

The LaTeX3 sources, released 2021-07-12, says in section ["23.7 Description of all possible tokens"](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/source3.pdf#section.23.7) of "Chapter 23: The **l3token** package /Token manipulation":

> - Expanding `\noexpand ⟨token⟩` (when the  `⟨token⟩` is expandable) results in an internal token, displayed (temporarily) as `\notexpanded: ⟨token⟩`, whose shape coincides with the `⟨token⟩` and whose meaning differs from `\relax`.

**Question 1:** Why the statement that the meaning **differs** from `\relax`?

If I do

```
\expandafter\show\noexpand\TeX
```

, then I get:

```
> \TeX=\relax.
<recently read> \notexpanded: \TeX
```

, which seems to imply that right after expanding `\noexpand` the meaning **equals** the meaning of the `\relax`-primitive.

If I do

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter\test\expandafter=\noexpand\TeX \show\test
```

, then I get:

```
> \test=\relax
```

, which seems to imply that right after expanding `\noexpand` the meaning **equals** the meaning of the `\relax`-primitive.

Besides this, TeXbook, "Chapter 20: Definitions (also called Macros)" says:

> - `\noexpand ⟨token⟩`. **The expansion is the `⟨token⟩` itself;** but that `⟨token⟩` is interpreted **as if its meaning were `\relax`** if it is a control sequence that would ordinarily be expanded by TeX's expansion rules.

Btw: This brings up more questions:

On the one hand (source3.pdf) there is the statement of the expansion of `\noexpand ⟨token⟩` **yielding an internal token**, displayed (temporarily) as `\notexpanded: ⟨token⟩` whose shape coincides with the `⟨token⟩`.

On the other hand (TeXbook) there is the statement of the expansion of `\noexpand ⟨token⟩` **yielding the `⟨token⟩` itself**.

These are two different statements.

**Question 2:** Are both statements correct?

**Question 3:** Which of these two statements is more precise?

Comment: the system has now added egreg's answer here as related https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387953/1090 but it's probably duplicate (even though my answer rather than your question discusses `\ifx`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

well...

```
\expandafter\show\noexpand\TeX

\expandafter\ifx\noexpand\TeX\relax \show Y\else\show N\fi

\expandafter\ifx\noexpand\TeX\TeX \show Y\else\show N\fi

\edef\zz{\ifnum0=0\else\fi}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\TeX\zz \show Y\else\show N\fi


\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\TeX\noexpand\LaTeX \show Y\else\show N\fi

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\TeX\noexpand\TeX \show Y\else\show N\fi

\bye
```

produces

```
> \TeX=\relax.
<recently read> \notexpanded: \TeX 
                                   
l.2 \expandafter\show\noexpand\TeX
                                  
? 
> the letter N.
l.4 ...\ifx\noexpand\TeX\relax \show Y\else\show N
                                                  \fi
? 
> the letter N.
l.6 ...er\ifx\noexpand\TeX\TeX \show Y\else\show N
                                                  \fi
? 
> the letter N.
l.10 ...and\expandafter\TeX\zz \show Y\else\show N
                                                  \fi
? 
> the letter Y.
l.13 ...and\expandafter\TeX\noexpand\LaTeX \show Y
                                                  \else\show N\fi
? 
> the letter Y.
l.15 ...xpand\expandafter\TeX\noexpand\TeX \show Y
                                                  \else\show N\fi
?
```

so although `\show` implies the token is `\relax` it is not `\ifx` equal to `\relax` or a frozen `\relax` or to the original token `\TeX`,  but is `\ifx` equal to other `\noexpand` produced tokens.

Answer (score 1):

To add a tiny bit more detail to David's answer here is an excerpt from “TeX: The program” (`texdoc tex`).

[image]

Here you can see that if `\noexpand` is follow by a control sequence the token is replaced by an internal token with code `frozen_dont_expand`. This is not reachable in any other way and hence not equal to `\relax`.